# How to fix PDF/a-1b compliance with embedded fonts that have zero charwidth

Tags: fonts, char, pdfa

We created a PDF/a-1b file and after checking it with preflight it didn't satisfy the requirements.

The problem is that we have embedded fonts that have zero charwidth.

How can we fix a document which has embedded fonts with zero characters that have zero width to make it pdf/a-1b compatible?

Answer (score 1):

Recreate the PDF/A-1 file with a tool that actually complies with the standard.

Comment: iTextSharp, PDF/AManager (pdftron) were tested but do not make it pdf/a-1b compatible.

Which tools do you suggest? or else: which method should be used to make it pdf/a-1b compatible?
Most tools don't even create valid pdf/a-1b files when there are fonts with zero-width characters.
(or they create an image of it, which is no option in our case)